# Search for strings in file and add certain line values to ArrayList

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner, delimiter, filereader

I am trying to write a method that reads a list from file1, search for list values in file2 and add parts of the line containing list values to arraylist until the string "Total" is reached.

here is sample file1:

```
AAA00020
AAA00021
AAA00022
AAA00023
AAA00024
AAA00025
AAA00026
```

file2:

```
ABC BANK
                                  ATM TRANSACTION SUMMARY

Institution: ABC BANK                          
Time 13:30:46     
Date: 13/05/2012      


1000 ATM AAA00022 01             10000.00/    0.00/      10000.00    100         289.00      1           0.00      0           0.00      0
2000 ATM AAB00023 02             20000.00/    0.00/      20000.00    200           0.00      0           0.00      0           0.00      0
3000 ATM AAC00024 03             30000.00/    0.00/      30000.00    300           0.00      0           0.00      0           0.00      0  ________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ 
Total                            60000.00/    0.00/      60000.00    600         289.00      1           0.00      0           0.00      0
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class atmTotals 
{       
    ArrayList <String> atmList = new ArrayList <String>();
    ArrayList <Atm> atmUs = new ArrayList <Atm>();

    public void getAtmList()
    {       
        try
        {
            FileReader in = new FileReader("ATMList.txt");              
            Scanner listIn = new Scanner(in);
            while (listIn.hasNextLine())
            {
                atmList.add(new String (listIn.next()));
            }
            for (String list : atmList)
            {
                //System.out.println(list);
            }
        }

        catch( FileNotFoundException fileNotFound)
        {
            System.err.println( "Error opening file.");
            System.exit(1);
        }           
        catch ( NoSuchElementException elementEx)
        {
            System.err.println( "Incorrect file format.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        catch ( IllegalStateException stateEx )
        {
            System.err.println( "Error reading from file.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

    }
    public void getAtmTotals()      
    {                       
        try
        {
            FileReader file = new FileReader ("ATMTOTAL.rep");
            Scanner in = new Scanner (file).useDelimiter("\\s+|/");
            for (String list : atmList)                         
            {                   
                while (in.hasNext() && !(in.next().contains("Total")))  
                {
                    String currentLine = in.next();
                    if (currentLine.contains(list))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Found String " + currentLine);
                        atmUs.add ( new Atm (in.next(), in.next(), in.nextFloat()));                            
                    }
                }
            }
            //System.out.print(atmUs);

            for ( Atm list : atmUs)
            {
                System.out.printf("%-15s%-3s%10.2f\n", list.getAtmID(), list.getBranchID(), list.getTotalAmt());
            }

        }
        catch( FileNotFoundException fileNotFound)
        {
            System.err.println( "Error opening file.");
            System.exit(1);
        }           
        catch ( NoSuchElementException elementEx)
        {
            System.err.println( "Incorrect file format.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        catch ( IllegalStateException stateEx )
        {
            System.err.println( "Error reading from file.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }               
}
```

Constructor:

```
public class Atm 
{
private String AtmID;
private String branchID;    
private float TotalAmt;


public Atm ( String AtmID, String branchID, float TotalAmt )
{
    this.AtmID = AtmID;
    this.branchID = branchID;
    this.TotalAmt = TotalAmt;
.....
```

I get output:

```
Found String AAA00022
Incorrect file format.
```

Comment: There are a couple of issues with the code can you re-edit the question with a full code listing that compiles. Comment out the Atm object instantiation, we don't need that as I think the problem is with the for and while loops and scanner. When do you close the Scanner?
 


  [1]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html

Comment: Ok looking at this now. You still need to call the close method on the scanner and I think you need to "restart" the scanner after you have processed the transaction summary file searching for one of the ATM ids.

Comment: Also can you update the question describing which values you expect to pass into the Atm constructor for the the ATM with ID AAA00022? (Also note that the input file test data id AAA00015 through to AAA00021 whereas the Transaction report is from AAA00022 onwards.

Comment: Sorry this is a result for ongoing changes to code, Also the transaction report posted is incomplete. I updated the code

Comment: I also removed the Scanner close(), i didn't want to implement it as yet until i figure out whats going on. It shouldn't affect the results.

Comment: I think the issue is with my Delimeter.

Comment: No need to apologise. I totally understand. There are two changes you can make to the question so that it will be easily answered. Change the data so there are no repeating numbers on a single line of the report, then change the last statement so that you describe calling how the Atm ctr will be invoked with the numbers from the report. Does that make sense?

Comment: The duplicates in the report is there for a purpose. The program has to stop scanning when the string "Total" is found.

Comment: My comment still stands. Making those changes (to the question) will make it easier for others to understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to put my head to it and I came up with the following. Works perfectly.

```
public void getAtmTotals(File file)     
    {

        Scanner rf = null;            
        for (String list : atmList)                         
        {               
        try
        {
            FileReader atmFile = new FileReader(file);
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile ("[\\s/\\s]+");
            rf = new Scanner (atmFile);                                        
            while (rf.hasNextLine())    
            {   
                if (rf.nextLine().contains("Total")) break;
                if (rf.nextLine().contains(list))
                {
                Scanner in = new Scanner(rf.nextLine()).useDelimiter(p);
                while (in.hasNext())                    
                    {                       
                        atmUs.add ( new Atm (in.next(), in.next(), in.next(), in.next(), in.nextFloat(), 
                                in.nextFloat(), in.nextFloat(), in.nextInt(), in.nextFloat(), in.nextInt(), 
                                in.nextFloat(), in.nextInt(), in.nextFloat(), in.nextInt() ) );                                                 
                    }               
                }
            }
        rf.close();
        }

        catch( FileNotFoundException fileNotFound)
        {
            System.err.println( "Error opening  " + file.getName());
            System.exit(1);
        }           

        catch ( NoSuchElementException elementEx)
        {
            System.err.println( "Incorrect " + file.getName() + " format");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        catch ( IllegalStateException stateEx )
        {
            System.err.println( "Error reading from " + file.getName());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        }

        System.out.print(atmUs);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what the exact problem is now, but you get an error when you add a `\r\n` on the last line because it expects another line after it.

Not quite sure why had to convert it - Java should accept both...

Comment: But don't do `\r\n`, because that would break portability. Do `System.getProperty("line.separator");`